# How my VM could interact in Ingress to a cluster Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

My Kubernetes cluster has a default subnet of 10.96.0.0/12, while my internal VMs, where my Kubernetes cluster is hosted, have a subnet of 172.0.0.0/24.

Is there a way for a virtual machine to communicate with a specific service in a namespace? Is there any way to assign a static IP to a service in a namespace?

Thank you.

I want service has the 172.0.0.0 static ip like the other VMs